# CS50: "expected prompt for input, not exit code of 0" not too sure what I am doing wrong here

Tags: c, cs50

I was just wondering what I did wrong here, because when the program is executed, it runs just fine. I'm a newbie at programming and am very lost. Any advise would be great!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Days in Month:\n");
    int days = GetInt();
    for (; days < 28 || days > 31; days = GetInt())
    {   
        printf("No month has that amount of days! Please try again.\n");
    }
    printf("Pennies on first day:\n");
    int pennies = GetInt();
    for (; pennies < 0; pennies = GetInt())
    {   
        printf("You can't have negative pennies! Please try again.\n");
    }
    if (pennies == 1) 
        printf("$%.2f",pow ((pennies + 1), (days - 1)));
    else 
        printf("$%.2f",pow (pennies, days));
}
```

Check50 yields:

```
~/workspace/chapter1/ $ check50 1617.chapter1.pennies pennies.c
:) pennies.c exists
:) pennies.c compiles
:( 28 days, 1 penny on first day
   \ expected output, but not "$134217728.00"
:( 31 days, 1 penny on first day
   \ expected output, but not "$1073741824.00"
:( 29 days, 2 pennies on first day
   \ expected output, but not "$536870912.00"
:( 30 days, 30 pennies on first day
   \ expected output, but not "$20589113209464899002378237447530552256..."
:) rejects days not 28, 29, 30, or 31
:( rejects non-positive pennies
   \ expected prompt for input, not exit code of 0
:) rejects a non-numeric days input of "foo"
:) rejects a non-numeric penny input of "foo"
:) rejects a non-numeric days input of ""
:) rejects a non-numeric penny input of ""
```

As you can see it says that it is accepting negative inputs and is not yielding the correct amount of money. Is this a bug in check50, or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Could you post what the problem is? I think you're just doing the math wrong.

Comment: @Schwern: Yep, you're right. I misread it with the extra unnecessary pairs of parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's [this assignment](http://cdn.cs50.net/ap/1516/problems/1/6/1-6.html), your math is wrong.

The assignment is what happens if your initial amount of pennies doubles every day for a month. If you start with 5 pennies, that means 5 then 10 then 20 then 40... 5 * 2 * 2 * 2 ... or 5 * 2<sup>N</sup> where `N` is the number of days.

But you have `pow(pennies, days)`. If `pennies = 5` and `days = 30` that's 5<sup>30</sup> which is something entirely different and very large.

What you need is `pennies * pow(2, days)`. And that's the number of pennies, so divide by 100 to get the dollar amount.

This isn't 100% correct, but since this is an exercise I leave the rest of the details up to you.

---

As to the "exit 0" problem, it's this:

```
for (; pennies < 0; pennies = GetInt())
{   
    printf("You can't have negative pennies! Please try again.\n");
}
```

You're allowing 0 pennies. You're supposed to reject that.

> If the user does not input a positive integer for the first day’s number of pennies, the program should prompt the user to retry.

As to why it says it didn't get a prompt, it gave you 0 pennies and expected to be prompted again. Whoever wrote the checking code didn't think to see if it got output.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I ended up implementing the standard geometric series formula that I haven't used since algebra 2: `printf("$%.2f\n",(((pennies * (1 - pow(2, days))) / (1 - 2)) / 100));`

Comment: @MatteoRehm You're welcome. You can simplify that. (1 - 2) is just -1. Dividing something by -1 is the same as multiplying it by -1. And the outer parens are unnecessary. `((pennies * (1 - pow(2, days))) * -1) / 100`. You should really do it in two steps for clarity (the compiler will probably make it one) and to get into the habit of keeping things as integers for as long as possible to avoid floating point inaccuracies. `long long accumulated_pennies = (pennies * (1 - pow(2, days))) * -1`, then `printf("$%.2f\n", accumulated_pennies / 100)`.